# Organizing data by filetype

Tags: python, macos, file-type

I am trying to sort a large number of files based off of their file extension.  A lot of the files are .doc, .docx, .xls, etc.

This is what I was thinking in my head, but if there is a simpler way to do things, let me know! I do have multiple files with the same extension, so I don't want it to create a new folder for that extension every time and overwrite the previous file. I also have a much larger list, but for this example I don't believe all of them are needed. The OS is MacOS.

```
import os, shutil

extList = ['.doc', '.docx', '.xls']

for ext in extList:
    os.mkdir(path + '/' + ext +'_folder')
    for file in os.listdir(filepath):
        if file.endswith(ext): #missing an indent
        print(file)
        shutil.copyfile(file + '/' + ext +'_folder' + file)
```

Also, if I run into a file that I do not have on my list, I would like it to go into a folder named 'noextlist'.

Comment: Are the files you are trying to sort in 1 folder or they are in folders and subfolders?

Comment: Within a 1 folder that has multiple sub folders

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I was able to create quickly

```
import os, re, shutil

DocFolder = r'...'#Your doc folder path
DocxFolder = r'...'#Your docx folder path
XlsFolder = r'...'#Your xls folder path
MiscFolder = r'...'#Your misc folder path

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'...'): #Your folder path you want to sort
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".doc"):
            sourceFolder = os.path.join(root,file)
            print sourceFolder
            shutil.copy2(sourceFolder,DocFolder)
        elif file.endswith(".docx"):
            sourceFolder = os.path.join(root,file)
            print sourceFolder
            shutil.copy2(sourceFolder,DocxFolder)
        elif file.endswith(".xls"):
            sourceFolder = os.path.join(root,file)
            print sourceFolder
            shutil.copy2(sourceFolder,XlsFolder)
        else:
            sourceFolder = os.path.join(root,file)
            print sourceFolder
            shutil.copy2(sourceFolder,MiscFolder)
```

Edit:The main function here is the `for root,dirs,files in os.walk` This allows the program to transverse through the provided path to search all files including the ones in the sub folder and sort it out accordingly.

Comment: I think this would work but it would be rather tedious for what I am doing.  The list I made was just an example, my actual list has 60 + extensions

Comment: Ah sorry, it was something I spat up in a matter of minutes. I am sure the other 2 answers can be more of help to you.

Answer (score 1):

```
import errno
import shutil
from os import listdir, mkdir
from os.path import splitext, join

# set for fast lookup
extList = set(['.doc', '.docx', '.xls'])

# source path
filepath = ...    

# dest path
path = ...

for f in listdir(filepath):
    # extract extension from file name
    ext = splitext(f)[1]
    if ext in extList:
        dir_ = join(path, "{}_folder".format(ext))
        try:
            mkdir(dir_)
        except OSError as e:
            if ex.errno != errno.EEXIST:
                raise  # raise if any other error than "already exists"
        dest = join(dir_, f)
    else:
        dest = join(path, "noextlist_folder", f)
    shutil.copy2(join(filepath, f), dest)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you like your solution but you need a way to rename files with duplicate names so that the extras don't disappear. You can check if the destination file already exists and construct a variant name by adding `_1`, `_2`, etc. to the filename until you find something unused.

```
newpathname = path + '/' + ext +'_folder' + "/" + file
n = 0
while os.path.exists(newpathname):
    n += 1
    base, ext = os.path.splitext(newpathname)
    newpathname = "%s_%d%s" % (base, n, ext)

shutil.copyfile(filepath+"/"+file, newpathname)
```

But your code has some other glitches, so here's a rewritten scanner. It uses `os.walk()` to descend into several levels of subdirectories (you don't say if that's needed or not), and it collects files of all extensions in one pass. And it constructs variant names as before.

```
import os, shutil
extList = ['.doc', '.docx', '.xls']
from os.path import join as joinpath

# Make sure the destination directories exist
for ext in extList:
    extdir = joinpath(path, ext[1:]+"_folder")
    if not os.path.exists(extdir):
        os.mkdir(extdir)

for dirname, _dirs, files in os.walk(filepath):
    for file in files:
        base, ext = os.path.splitext(file)
        if ext not in extList:
            continue
        destpath = joinpath(path, ext[1:]+"_folder")
        n = 0
        newpathname = joinpath(destpath, file)
        # If the new name is in use, find an unused variant
        while os.path.exists(newpathname):
            n += 1
            newfile = "%s_%d%s" % (base, n, ext)
            newpathname = joinpath(path, newfile)

        sh.copy(joinpath(dirname, file), newpathname)  # or other copy method
```

Comment: I am not worried much about duplicate file names because most of the files are named based off of their MD5 hash value.  I was concerned with Python creating duplicate file extension folders and overwriting a previous folder.  For some reason this did not workout for me, but it may be because of the code I have for the hashing of the files.

Comment: Directories are not files: Creating a directory is impossible if it exists; it will raise an error, but will never overwrite anything. But if that's all, you can simply create all the directories before moving your files (you're working with a fixed list of extensions, so you know which directories you need).

Comment: I added the code to create the directories. What problem did you have with the script? I might have made a mistake somewhere.